# Rewriting a URL before Rails route checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm configuring my routes with a pattern like `https://example.com/:blog_id/:post_id`. What I'd like to do is optionally and sometimes fill the `blog_id` based on some external HTTP request headers, like the `Host` header in combination with the country. I'd need to look up the database as well, preferably using Active Record, so it's not something I can do in a Rack middleware.

Is there any way to wrap all routes with a rewrite method of some sort, like

```
def rewriter(url)
    ...
    return new_url
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
    scoped_with_rewriter :rewriter do 
        ...
    end
end
```

Example:

I have the following route:

```
get '/:blog_id/:post_id', to: 'posts#show'
```

which will work great on `example.com/super-blog/awesome-post`.

I'd like to write a wrapper and serve my site on `superblog.example.com` or any other domain (not just subdomain). In this case the URL visited will become `superblog.example.com/awesome-post`. I do not want to change the routes because both forms are valid - is there a way to change the path portion of the URL from `/awesome-post` to `/super-blog/awesome-post` programmatically (based on the `Host` header or anything else) before the routing process begins?

Comment: It sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. What do you mean by "fill the blog_id"? `blog_id` is this route pattern is just a "placeholder", the identifier of the parameter which will be resolved based on the actual request. So, you want the solution where for the request, say, `http://example.com/foo/bar` the `blog_id` param will be resolved not into `foo` but something else based on some additional logic? Or what? Could you please provide (maybe simplidfied) example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov have clarified the question and added an example.

Comment: So, in other words, you want the same resource to be available at `/:blog_id/:post_id` under some circumstances, but at `/:post_id` under other ones (or vice versa), right? But why do you want to hack the router in a confusing ("non-conventional", let's say) way instead of just defining both routes statically and pointing them to the very same controller action (with or without redirects)?